# Lightread in the message menu

Tags: 12.04, messaging-menu, lightread

I was wondering if it were possible to put light read into the messaging menu, I have tried to create the file to place it there but it didn't work. I was wondering how to get Lightread to show up in the messaging menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a quick answer to this.  You may be able to hack in a fix (based on your post stating you attempted to create a file to place it there), but in general this appears to be a bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightread/+bug/1022536

I would go to that bug, mark that it affects you so it gets additional attention, and subscribe to the bug to see if any patches go by that you could test, or if a new release is submitted that fixes the issue.

I don't think this really closes the issue, but an admin may determine that it does.